# How to display current date in page subtitle? (wordpress theme "story")

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, shortcode

I´m trying to make the page subtitle (http://www.nashebistro.cz/) the current date.

I´ve tried using shortcode (https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-for-current-date/) and Php `<?php echo date('Y'); ?>` but the shortcode doesn´t show correctly and the Php code shows nothing.

I would really appreciate any solution, tip, advice.

[This is how the settings of the subtitle looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObSwM.png)

Comment: Do you have any code to go with this?

Comment: Yes, I edited the original question. (<?php echo date('Y'); ?>)

Answer (score 0):

Do this. You have to create a new DateTime instance and format it into a string that can be read for html.

```
<?php echo date_format(new DateTime('Y'),"Y"); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. To be honest - I´m quite lost. I´ve tried putting your code into the subtitle settings, but then it still does´t show anything (same as when I tried: <?php echo date('Y'); ?>).

Comment: On your site it looks like you commented it out. Remove the <!-- at the beginning of the element and the and finish it with just ?> not ?-->

Comment: That may be the main problem!! The theme is maybe commenting it out automatically. Because I typed it without "<!--". Hmm.. But.. how do I stop it from doing it automatically.. Maybe I must put the code manually into code and not from the theme edit dashboard. But where do I put it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `<?php the_time('Y'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with native WordPress fonction "date_i18n". So you can display month in text (in your wordpress language)

```
<?php echo date_i18n( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n

Or use it with ShortCode, past this in your functions.php

```
if (!function_exists('topdaweb_shortcode_currentdate')) :
    function topdaweb_shortcode_currentdate($atts) {
        return date_i18n( 'Y-m-d' );
    }
    add_shortcode('currentdate', 'topdaweb_shortcode_currentdate');
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I´ve tried your code, but nothing shows up (http://nashebistro.cz - under "menu" = nothing).

Comment: @RomanŠtěrba Sorry i gaved you 2 answer. First its when you want to edit your theme file. And the other one its the easy one. Using Shortcode. Just past the function in your functions.php and in your page use that shortcode you juste create [currentdate]